# How to build boost required modules only?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I just started compiling boost C++ libraries. With the following commands I issued it is building whole of the boost libraries, which is time consuming, and is not necessary for my need.

Just unpacked the `boost_1_49_0.7z` archive and from `Visual Studio 2010 command line tool` I ran `bootstrap.bat` and it created the `b2` executable.

Using this executable I ran `b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage` to build the libraries.

At this moment all I need is the "signals" module to be built.

What switch commands need to be supplied to the bootstrap created executable to compile and build only those specific libraries?

Comment: [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) may be helpful.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Where can I find the bcp tool. I could locate bcp folder with its sources in tool\ directory. OR.. How ot build the bcp tool?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`b2.exe --help` outputs the following.

`--show-libraries        Displays the list of Boost libraries that require
                          build and installation steps, then exit.`

`--with-<library>        Build and install the specified <library>
                          If this option is used, only libraries
                          specified using this option will be built.`

Also is possible to use the `-jX` option to compile BOOST in X processes in parallel.