# Boost: Install headers only

Tags: c++, windows, boost

How do I output all the boost headers to a path containing the boost version, without compiling anything or installing any already compiled libraries, in a platform-independent manner?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Changed the wording to have an explicit rather than an implicit question

Comment: I'm not understanding why you would "have to specify `--without-<lib>` for each and every library". Just run the command normally? Perhaps you can be clearer about the problem you are facing with the documented installation instructions.

Comment: If I do that I will compile all the boost libraries, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: Will it? I haven't tried it, but I do know that in my setup I explicitly name the libraries to build with `--with-<lib>`. Just don't write those? (Or perhaps the lack of any implies `--with-all`; is that what we're saying?)

Comment: Doesn't `--with-xxx` implicitly exclude all other libraries? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10024460/241631. If you want to use the header-only parts of Boost, then is running b2 even required? I think you can just extract Boost to whatever include path you want and start using it.

Comment: @Praetorian Sure, I can use `--with-<lib>` and only compile a single library but that is still one too many.  
@LightnessRacesinOrbit Default behavior is to compile all libraries, using `--with-<lib>` makes the build only include the libraries specified using `--with`

Comment: @Jonas: Okay then. A bit of context helps your question be quickly understood. Anyway isn't this going to be answerable only by reading the documentation? Was there a particular page that was confusing, or that you needed clarification on? I'm not really sure what you're asking us to do here.

Comment: You could try using the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool to extract the header-only parts, but if you just want all the headers what is wrong with just copying them, why do you need to use `b2` to do it?

Answer (score 8):

Why do you think you need to use `b2` to do it?

If you don't want to build anything and just want to copy the headers then just copy the headers:

```
mkdir inc_dir
cp -R ./boost ./inc_dir/
```

If you want the headers in `inc_dir/boost-1.59.0` then do that instead:

```
mkdir inc_dir/boost-1.59.0
cp -R ./boost ./inc_dir/boost-1.59.0/
```

If you don't want to have to name the directory yourself then get it from the `boost/version.hpp` header:

```
ver=`awk '/define.*BOOST_LIB_VERSION/ {print $3}' boost/version.hpp | sed 's/"//g'`
mkdir inc_dir/boost_${ver}_0/
cp -R ./boost ./inc_dir/boost_${ver}_0/
```

But this seems like a rather silly request now ... is it really something you need to do so often that extracting the version needs to be automated? How many versions of Boost do you install, where you don't start with a tarball such as `boost_1_59_0.tar.bz2` that means you need to know the version anyway? I used to install multiple versions of Boost across multiple operating systems at previous jobs, and when starting the process never had a problem of not knowing which version of Boost I was working with.

Comment: Edited the question to include a "version" criteria, my mistake. I wanted to use `b2` because it is aware of the boost version, rather than extracting that myself

Comment: What does "output all the headers with version" mean? The headers are just copied, what has the version got to do with it? You can always do `mkdir inc_dir/boost-1.59.0; cp -R boost inc_dir/boost-1.59.0;` if you want them in a directory that includes the version.

Comment: A path like `boost_1_54_0/boost/...` which differentiates versions

Comment: OK, you should have said so. The comment above already shows how to do that.

Comment: Manually specifying the version achives nothing, I have to change it for every version then. If you want I can reword the question to omit `b2` if that simplifies the question.

Comment: Yes, wording the question so it asks what you **actually want to do** is always useful. Answer updated to find the version automatically.

Comment: I would argue that I did specify that, albeit in a wording that was more complex than required. Question updated, I can probably settle for a Windows version but a platform-independent would be nicer, hence why I looked to `b2`.

Comment: There was originally no mention of wanting the version in the installation path. You could have just said "I want the headers installed to `/some/path/boost_$version` but don't want to build any of the libraries" and it would have been perfectly clear, instead of mentioning `b2` at all (instead you described an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Apologies, I was blinded by my own solution attempts and my rapidly evolving question. Anyway `b2` was for the sake of platform-independence. However it seems it is not possible to use `b2`, but you pointed me in the right direction with `version.hpp` so I can roll a simple python script. If you want to update your answer with a platform-independent solution I will accept it.