# `uint_fast32_t` not found in namespace `boost` for boost > 1.74.0

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile boost from sources but getting the error below.
It works fine for all versions of boost up to 1.74.0 but it breaks for anything newer than that.
Note that I am compiling a subset of boost modules, std::regex only.
Is there anything that changed on this version that makes these types unavailable?

```bash
clang-linux.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/clang-linux-14/release/link-static/visibility-hidden/posix_api.o
libs/regex/build/../src/posix_api.cpp:90:4: error: no type named 'uint_fast32_t' in namespace 'boost'; did you mean simply 'uint_fast32_t'?
   boost::uint_fast32_t flags = (f & REG_PERLEX) ? 0 : ((f & REG_EXTENDED) ? regex::extended : regex::basic);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   uint_fast32_t
```

This script causes the error:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -exo pipefail

INSTALL_DIR=/ssd/tmp/install
TMPDIR=/ssd/tmp
TAG=boost-1.78.0

cd $TMPDIR
rm -rf boost
git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
git checkout $TAG

allsm=" tools/build                                                                              
        tools/bcp 
        tools/boost_install
        tools/boostdep 
        libs/regex 
        libs/config 
        libs/predef 
        libs/core  
        libs/detail  
        libs/headers
        libs/integer"

for sm in $allsm; do
    git submodule update --init $sm
done


#export LD=/usr/local/bin/ld.lld
#export CC='/usr/local/bin/clang'
#export CXX='/usr/local/bin/clang++'
#export CXXFLAGS='-O3 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++'
#export LDFLAGS="-lc++abi -lc++"


./bootstrap.sh
#--with-toolset=clang
./b2 headers
./b2 install -q -a \
        --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR/local \
        --build-type=minimal \
        --layout=system \
        --disable-icu \
        --with-regex \
        variant=release link=static runtime-link=static \
        threading=single address-model=64 architecture=x86 
#        toolset=clang
```

However it works if you change the git tag from `boost-1.78.0` to `boost-1.71.0`.

Comment: compiler, platform and build command would be helpful

Comment: I realize I do not have a minimum reproducible example - in this case the build is really complex as it is an external project within another project.

Comment: This gist fails with the same cause (uint_fast32_t) both gcc and clang stock on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS https://gist.github.com/HFTrader/689df916ea816e52e673905f82cccfda
However it works fine for boost 1.71.0

Comment: My guess would be its because you aren't checking out/updating all the submodules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking out all of the submodules, the simplest solution is to just follow the [docs](https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview) and run:

```bash
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
```

or:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:boostorg/boost.git
git submodule update --init
```

After adding `libs/throw_exception`, and `libs/assert` to the submodules in your script it works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Here's the dockerfile I used for testing:

```
From ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install g++ git -y

RUN git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git

RUN cd boost && git checkout boost-1.78.0

RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init tools/build
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init tools/bcp
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init tools/boost_install
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init tools/boostdep
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/regex
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/config
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/predef
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/core
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/detail
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/headers
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/integer
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/assert
RUN cd boost && git submodule update --init libs/throw_exception

RUN cd boost && ./bootstrap.sh
RUN cd boost && ./b2 headers
RUN cd boost && ./b2 install -q -a \
        --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR/local \
        --build-type=minimal \
        --layout=system \
        --disable-icu \
        --with-regex \
        variant=release link=static runtime-link=static \
        threading=single address-model=64 architecture=x86
```

Comment: Adding these `libs/throw_exception` and `libs/assert` did solve the problem.

Comment: The issue  is that cloning the entire boost was overwhelming our bandwidth (expensive) and dragging build times way too long as we use several versions of boost across many platforms. We cannot afford that.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Why clone from github at all? It'd be much easier and probably more efficient to just download the release packages. Or use a package manager like vcpkg or conan

Comment: Alan, we have very special requirements. We use our own compilers (custom llvm with our own passes) and heavily patched sources. It just does not fit vcpkg or conan.

Comment: Still bothers me why these two missing libraries would not break the build. I'd expect something like `#include <boost/assert.hpp>` would bomb straight away

Comment: It did for me? Maybe you just need to look further up in the bulid log for the missing include error? Modern compilers try to keep plowing ahead after encountering an error

Comment: I don't see a custom compiler stopping you from using conan (you might need to adjust the [settings](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/custom_settings.html))

Comment: We used Conan but it became a nightmare due to versioning hell. For example, we build for different architectures (vanilla x86-64,skylake,icelake-server,knl) and Conan requires customizing tags.  We have a straight bash script that is much easier to maintain across our platforms which goes from Raspberry PI to high-end servers and FPGAs.  Also it is also sort of unanimous here, a dislike for Conan as a tool but that is subjective.

Comment: Oh so there was a missing include break? I completely missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Since Boost 1.76, Boost.Regex is [a header-only library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html):

> This is a header only library provided your compiler supports C++11 or later. Support for C++03 compilers is still present, but is now deprecated and may be removed without further notice!
>
> The only people that still need to build the external libboost_regex library are those that are either:
>
> - Using the library in C++03 mode, or,
> - Using the deprecated POSIX C API's

Since you're compiling as C++11 or above, you should not need to build the libboost_regex library, so you can remove the `--with-regex` option.

Comment: But I am not requesting to build the regex library, boost is building it on its own. It should just install it.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher you specified `--with-regex`; remove that. You may want to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188751/boost-install-headers-only

Comment: I removed `--with-regex` and it still fails.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher OK, try `--without-regex` then.

Comment: It might be deprecated but it still builds correctly (if you've actually checked out all the required headers)

Comment: Yes, if the right submodules are included it builds even with `--with-regex`

Comment: Sure, but you don't actually need that; there's no point building and linking against the library.